# vh and calc is not working on safari and ant design

Tags: css, reactjs, iphone, safari, antd

I tried to use antdesign drawer in react and it doesnt scroll properly on safari.
Currently my code looks like.

```
<Drawer
      placement="right"
      closable={!!fullCheckout}
      onClose={() => setVisible(false)}
      visible={visible}
      getContainer={false}
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        height: `calc(100vh - ${view === "MobileView" ? "50px" : "55px"})`,
        top: `${view === "MobileView" ? 0 : "55px"}`,
      }}
      width={fullCheckout ? "100%" : 455}
    >
<CheckoutDrawContainer>
<TopContainer />
<BottomContainer />
</CheckoutDrawContainer>
</Drawer>
```

The issue is the scroll is not working properly on safari, iphone.

```
export const CheckoutDrawerContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
  height: ${({ view }) => (view !== "MobileView" ? "calc(100vh - 50px)" : "")};
`;

export const CheckoutDrawerTopContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: ${primary[0]};
  height: 258px;
  padding: 0 21px;
  padding-top: 27px;
  z-index: 9;
`;

export const CheckoutDrawerBottomContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 21px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  height: 500px;
`;
```

I think it is related to the `vh` on safari, iphone.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what 'not working properly' means? vh on IOS gives a fixed amount - so is a bit longer than the actual viewport when the full tab info is shown at the top of the screen by Safari - it gives the right dimension when the user scrolls as the info shrinks.

Comment: This is the mp4 file which shows the current state and will give you the answer. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zLI54pLwmeK_FWV9AUkmyqdggqf379Yu/view?usp=sharing Thank you for your attention.